# How to determine features location in a layer in open layers?

Tags: openlayers

I have a wfs protocol with vector layer. In which i am using icons for features. How can i determine feature's location so that i want to know the exact space taken by icon of feature.

Comment: Your question is not very clear... Could you explain it in more detail

Comment: I am asking for,how we can find out icons collision and labels collision in a layer in openlayers? @Odoakr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can find out feature collision in PreFeature insert function of OpenLayer.Layer.Vector and by point1.distanceTo(point2);
If distance is too small we can ignore one point which has low priority.